# Nilpotent elements of derivation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $K$ be algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (for simplicity, we can assume that $K=\mathbb{C}$) and $B$ be integral domain, finitely generated as $K$-algebra. $D$ - derivation on B. Let for some $x \in B$ and natural $k \geq 2$ exist such $n$, that $D^n(x^k)=0$. Is it true, that for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ $D^m(x)=0$?

Comment: This is not true without some extra hypothesis.  Suppose $K$ has characteristic $p>0$ and $B$ is the polynomial ring $K[x]$.  Let $D$ be the derivation $x\frac{d}{dx}$.  Then $D^m(x)=x$ for all $m$.  However, $D(x^p)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I meant $K$ to be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (for simplicity, we can assume that $K=\mathbb{C}$).  Thanks for your example, fixed the question.

Comment: As written $x$ could be nilpotent so there's nothing stopping $x^k = 0$. Do you want $B$ to be an integral domain?

Comment: Yes, $B$ is supposed to be an integral domain, thanks for the correction, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a counterexample - consider derivation $D = x^{-1} \frac{d}{dx}$ on $B=\mathbb{C}[x, x^{-1}]$. $D^2(x^2) = 0$, but for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ $D^m(x) \neq 0$.